# java Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java

I would like to display the flags as button using GUI.

however, my code is not working, the expected output should look something like this
[image]

the images of the flag are saved in the same file with file names being "USA.png", "Spain.png" etc.

this is the code i have now

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Olympic 
{
    private int NO;
    private String country;
    private double[] score;
    private int rank;
    
    public Olympic(String country)
    {
        this.country = country;
    }
    
    public Olympic (Olympic oly)
    {
        this(oly.country);
    }
    
    public int getRank()
    {
        return rank;
    }
    
    public String getName()
    {
        return country;
    }
}

class OlympicFrame extends JFrame
{
    private JButton[] jbArray = new JButton[12];
    
    private final String[] countryArray = {"USA", "Spain", "China", "Japan", "Italy", "Germany", 
    "France", "Brazil", "Netherland", "Poland", "Russia", "Ukraine"};
    
    private ArrayList<Olympic> alist = new ArrayList <Olympic> ();
    
    //private JLabel rank = new JLabel();
    
    
    public OlympicFrame()
    {
        super ("Olympic 2020");
        setLayout (new GridLayout (4, 3));
        
        constructAList();
        

        
        for (int i = 0; i<jbArray.length; i++)
        {
            getContentPane().add(jbArray[i]);
        }
        

        jbArray = new JButton [countryArray.length];
        
        for (int i = 0; i<jbArray.length; i++)
        {
            jbArray[i] = new JButton(alist.get(i).getName());
            ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon (alist.get(i).getName() +".png");
            
            jbArray[i].setIcon(ic);

        }

    }
    
    private void constructAList()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<countryArray.length; i++)
        {
            alist.add(new Olympic(countryArray[i]));
        }
    }
    

}

class aaa
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        OlympicFrame of = new OlympicFrame();
        of.setSize (300, 100);
        of.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        of.setVisible (true);
    }
}
```

i have been receiving this error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1095)
        at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:419)
        at OlympicFrame.<init>(ask.java:58)
        at aaa.main(ask.java:90)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with your code order you added the buttons to contentpane before initializing them, change them as below:

```
jbArray = new JButton [countryArray.length];

for (int i = 0; i<jbArray.length; i++)
{
    jbArray[i] = new JButton(alist.get(i).getName());
    ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon (alist.get(i).getName() +".png");
    
    jbArray[i].setIcon(ic);

}

for (int i = 0; i< jbArray.length; i++)
{
    getContentPane().add(jbArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: oh! haha thank you for the help

Comment: i have another question, will you be able to help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676382/java-gui-show-ranking-in-sequence

Answer (score 0):

Your `jbArray[i]` is assigning in line 66 but you are trying to access it on line 58. You will need to move the first for loop below the second for loop

Comment: i have another question, will you be able to help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676382/java-gui-show-ranking-in-sequence